# Connect Google Cloud CDN with Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-cdn

It's possible to connect CloudCDN with CloudFunctions?

The objective is to resize images and serve them. The actual architecture use balanced servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment it’s not possible to connect Cloud CDN directly with Cloud Functions but there is [a feature request for this](https://issuetracker.google.com/36817713). In order to be notified by email of any changes to this thread, you can click on the star icon.

As a workaround you could setup a load balancer with Cloud CDN enabled and configure the load balanced instances as proxy to redirect the request to Cloud Functions. However this requires having the load balanced instances up and running to receive the requests.